# Quantlib - is Tolerance still an option?

Tags: c++, quantlib

Some older c++ Quantlib examples have code like this

```
mcengine3 = MakeMCAmericanEngine<PseudoRandom>(bsmProcess)
        .withSteps(100)
        .withAntitheticVariate()
        .withCalibrationSamples(4096)
        .withTolerance(0.02)
        .withSeed(mcSeed);
```

If I don't comment out the `.withTolerance(0.02)` I get a compiler error that `withTolerance` is not a member.

What is the current way to do this, or is this an anachronism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method was renamed to `withAbsoluteTolerance`, to make it clear that the tolerance should be a dollar amount and not a percentage of the price.  From the git logs, the change was made in November 2008.